# Is it possible for two ExecutorServices to share a thread pool?

Tags: java, concurrency, threadpool

I've got a collection of records to process, and the processing can be parallelized, so I've created an [ExecutorService](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) (via [Executors#newCachedThreadPool()](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newCachedThreadPool())). The processing of an individual record is, itself, composed of parallelizable steps, so I'd like to use another `ExecutorService`. Is there an easy way to make this new one use the same underlying thread pool? Is it even desirable? Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To answer your question: **no**, two `ExecutorService` objects **cannot** share a thread pool. However you can share an `ExecutorService` between your objects, or alternatively create several Executors, as necessary, though this is less recommended.

Best solution: share the `Executor` between your objects.

Answer (score 6):

Short answer: No.

Longer answer: You will need your own implementation to do that. `ExecutorService` is an interface and `AbstractExecutorService` is quite easy to implement.
If you want two `ExecutorService` sharing same ThreadPool (e.g. with different maximum active thread value), you may use proxy pattern to make ThreadPool sharing `ExecutorService`.

Comment: Thank you! The proxy pattern would be beautiful here. Duplicating Doug Lea's code for a pluggable thread pool would have been too error-prone.

Comment: (My use case was I needed to wait until all the tasks finished per Executor. That is, use the shutdown()/awaitTermination() methods)

Answer (score 2):

Can you just pass a reference to the existing ExecutorService to your worker objects?

```
public class Task implements Runnable {
    private final ExecutorService threadPool;
    private final SubTask[] subtasks;

    public Task(ExecutorService threadPool) {
        this.threadPool = threadPool;
        this.subtasks = createSubtasksIGuess();
    }

    public void run() {
        for(SubTask sub : subtasks)
            threadPool.submit(sub);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few good reasons to want to do this, such as separate bounds and metrics per queue. AFAIK, Cassandra 2.1 gained not insignificantly from using an executor service implementation with a shared thread pool; the code is at https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/trunk/src/java/org/apache/cassandra/concurrent/SEPExecutor.java.

Comment: Of course, the original problem calls for a straightforward use of the fork/join task API's that are available in Java 7.

Comment: Another use-case I had recently is to have a single thread pool with a single queue but two executors where one uses `AbortPolicy` and the other `CallerRunsPolicy`.