# Using a shared ExecutorService as a task queue, how do I know when a job is complete?

Tags: java, concurrency, threadpool

I have a JobService that processes larger jobs.  Jobs are dynamically subdivided into multiple tasks, tasks also might generate sub-tasks, etc, so its not possible to predict the total number of tasks for a job.  Each task queues itself to run via `ExecutorService.submit(...)`  The problem is it seems like I have to create a separate ExecutorService for each job, since the only way to tell when the 'job queue' is complete is to use `ExecutorService.awaitTermination(...)`.  This seems inefficient though, because [I can't share a single threadpool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/368613/is-it-possible-for-two-executorservices-to-share-a-thread-pool) between the jobs and their ExecutorService.

I'm looking for some alternatives, I was thinking of using an AtomicInteger for each job.  Incrementing it when I submit a new task, decrementing it when a task finishes.  But then I have to poll for when it is zero, and that seems messy, as well as some exception handling mess.

It seems like there must be a better solution?

Comment: Have you examined [`CompletionService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletionService.html)? You can use [`submit`](http://goo.gl/lmHAP) with a value that associates it with the `Job` being completed.

Comment: Have a look at [the javadoc of ExecutorCompletionService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorCompletionService.html) for a sample code.

Comment: I did look at `CompletionService`, but it didn't seem to be what I want since I don't care about processing the individual results, I just want to know when they are all done, so the poll()/take() one by one seemed messy, I really just want to know when the completionQueue is empty.  Maybe I should look at extending it for my purposes.

Comment: Have you looked at the invokeAll method of the ExecutorSerice? Not sure if this will meet your needs or not

Comment: InvokeAll was what I was using originally, but the problem is some of the tasks I submit to invokeAll will in turn submit more tasks, I need to know when they are done as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Submit returns a Future object that can be used to wait on completion of tasks.  You could keep track of these and add a method that recursively blocks until all subtasks are done.  This way you can reuse the executor wherever you need to.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean;

public class JobExecutor {
    ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);

    private class Task implements Runnable {
        private final String name;
        private final Task[] subtasks;
        private final ExecutorService executorService;
        private volatile boolean started = false;
        private Future<?> taskFuture;

        // Separate list from subtasks because this is what you'll probably
        // actually use as you may not be passing subtasks as constructor args
        private final List<Task> subtasksToWaitOn = new ArrayList<Task>();

        public Task(String name, ExecutorService executorService,
                Task... subtasks) {
            this.name = name;
            this.executorService = executorService;
            this.subtasks = subtasks;
        }

        public synchronized void start() {
            if (!started) {
                started = true;
                taskFuture = executorService.submit(this);
            }
        }

        public synchronized void blockTillDone() {
            if (started) {
                try {
                    taskFuture.get();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Handle
                } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                    // TODO Handle
                }
                for (Task subtaskToWaitOn : subtasksToWaitOn) {
                    subtaskToWaitOn.blockTillDone();
                }
            } else {
                // TODO throw exception
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            for (Task subtask : subtasks) {
                subtask.start();
                subtasksToWaitOn.add(subtask);
            }
            System.out.println("My name is: " + name);
        }
    }

    void testSubmit() {
        Task subsubTask1 = new Task("Subsubtask1", executorService);
        Task subtask1 = new Task("Subtask1", executorService, subsubTask1);
        Task subtask2 = new Task("Subtask2", executorService);
        Task subtask3 = new Task("Subtask3", executorService);
        Task job = new Task("Job", executorService, subtask1, subtask2,
                subtask3);
        job.start();
        job.blockTillDone();
        System.out.println("Job done!");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new JobExecutor().testSubmit();
    }
}
```

Prints out:

```
My name is: Job
My name is: Subtask1
My name is: Subtask2
My name is: Subtask3
My name is: Subsubtask1
Job done!
```

Comment: Thanks!  This is kind of the direction I was going, the problem is tasks are added dynamically not up front, so in blockTillDone() I will get ConcurrentModificationExceptions on the subtaskToWaitOn loop.

Comment: This solution took that into account.  Block till done first blocks until the run method of the parent task is finished (taskFuture.get()).  At that point, all of the subtasks have been added.  I'm actually adding all of the subtasks to subtasksToWaitOn inside the run method to simulate dynamic addition of the subtasks.

Comment: You were right, I had some extra junk that was causing the problem.  I've got this working fairly well now. Thats for your help!  For the googlers out there, I think I still want to go with Fork-Join pool eventually, but I'll wait until our project gets to Java7.

Answer (score 1):

If you're on java7 (or java6 with the backport library http://www.cs.washington.edu/homes/djg/teachingMaterials/grossmanSPAC_forkJoinFramework.html ), you might want to consider a Fork-Join pool for this sort of thing:

```
class MainTask extends RecursiveTask<Long> {

    @Override
    protected Long compute() {
        SubTask subtask0 = new SubTask(0L);
        SubTask subtask1 = new SubTask(1L);
        SubTask subtask2 = new SubTask(2L);
        SubTask subtask3 = new SubTask(3L);
        SubTask subtask4 = new SubTask(4L);
        SubTask subtask5 = new SubTask(5L);

        subtask1.fork();
        subtask2.fork();
        subtask3.fork();
        subtask4.fork();
        subtask5.fork();

        return subtask0.compute() +
                subtask1.join() +
                subtask2.join() +
                subtask3.join() +
                subtask4.join() +
                subtask5.join();
    }

}

class SubTask extends RecursiveTask<Long> {
    private Long rawResult = null;

    private Long expected = null;

    public SubTask(long expected) {
        this.expected = expected;
    }

    @Override
    protected Long compute() {
        return expected;
    }
}

public static void main( String[] args )
{
    ForkJoinPool forkJoinPool = new ForkJoinPool();
    Long result = forkJoinPool.invoke(new MainTask());
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

obviously this has hardcoded subtasks, but there's no reason you can't pass parameters to your main task, and use that to generate subtasks.  The subtasks themselves don't all have to be of the same type, but they should all extend RecursiveTask.   Realistically if a task generates subtasks (like MainTask above), at least one of the subtasks should have "compute" called directly on it (rather and a fork and a join), so that the current thread can execute some computations, and let other threads do the rest.

Comment: ps:  this sort of thing is exactly what ForkJoinPool was intended for.

Comment: I'm stuck with java6 for now, but this does look like the most elegant/correct solution, I'll play with the jsr166 stuff some more.